# 'Int' object has no attribute 'number of files' - Classes & Functions

Tags: python-3.x, function, class, object, attributes

I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong, as I am almost absolutely certain that I've referenced variables and all correctly.

I'm fairly new to using functions, and have just started learning to use Python classes a day ago.

I'm guessing that it has something to do with my sequential steps of code, or is that because I've converted the *numfiles* input to an *int()* in line 20 of code.

I have attached my code below. Please help me out thanks in advance :)

```
import csv
import numpy as np


''' DEFINING MAIN CONTROL'''

def main():
    number_of_files()
    a = Calculate_RMSE_Assess_Models()
    a.number_of_files = no_of_files
    a.pathlist()
    a.out_path()
    a.open_read_write_files()


''' DEFINING NUMBER OF FILES TO ITERATE THROUGH '''

def number_of_files():
    numfiles = input("Enter the number of files to iterate through: ")
    numfilesnumber = int(numfiles)
    return numfilesnumber

no_of_files = number_of_files()


''' DEFINING CLASS OF ALL '''
class Calculate_RMSE_Assess_Models:

    def __init__(self, number_of_files = 0):
        self.number_of_files = no_of_files


    def pathlist(self):
        filepathlist = []
        while self.number_of_files > 0:
            path = input("Enter the filepath of the input file: ")
            filepathlist.append(path)
            no_of_files = no_of_files - 1
        return filepathlist

    list_filepath = pathlist(no_of_files)

    def out_path():
        path = input("Enter the file path of output path: ")
        return path

    file_out_path = outpath()

    def open_read_write_files():
        with open('{d[0]}'.format(d=list_filepath), 'r') as csvinput, open('{d[1]}'.format(d=list_filepath), 'r') as csvinput2, open('d{[2]}'.format(d=list_filepath), 'r') as csvinput3, open('{d}'.format(d=file_out_path), 'w') as csvoutput:
            reader, reader2, reader3 = csv.reader(csvinput, csvinput2, csvinput3)                                               #1: Decision Forest, 2: Boosted Decision Tree, 3: ANN
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csvoutput, lineterminator='\n', fieldnames = ['oldRMSE', 'Decision Forest Regression RMSE', 'Boosted Decision Tree Regression RMSE', 'Neural Network Regression RMSE', 'Old Accurate Predictions', 'Old Inaccurate Predictions', 'Decision Forest Accurate Predictions', 'Decision Forest Inaccurate Predictions', 'Boosted Decision Tree Accurate Predictions', 'Boosted Decision Tree Inaccurate Predictions', 'Neural Network Accurate Predictions', 'Neural Network Inaccurate Predictions'])

            #######################################
            #For Decision Forest Predictions
            headerline = next(reader)
            emptyl=[]
            for row in reader:
                emptyl.append(row)

            #Calculate RMSE
            DecFSqResidSum = 0
            for row in emptyl:
                for cell in row:
                    if cell == row[-3]:
                        DecFSqResidSum = float(cell) + DecFSqResidSum
            DecFSqResidAvg = DecFSqResidSum / len(emptyl)
            DecForest_RMSE = np.sqrt(DecFSqResidAvg)

            #Constructing No. of Correct/Incorrect Predictions
            DecisionForest_Accurate = 0
            DecisionForest_Inaccurate = 0
            Old_Accurate = 0
            Old_Inaccurate = 0
            for row in emptyl:
                for cell in row:
                    if cell == row[-2] and 'Accurate' in cell:
                        Old_Accurate += 1
                    else:
                        Old_Inaccurate += 1
                    if cell == row[-1] and 'Accurate' in cell:
                        DecisionForest_Accurate += 1
                    else:
                        DecisionForest_Inaccurate += 1


            ######################################
            #For Boosted Decision Tree
            headerline2 = next(reader2)
            emptyl2=[]                                      #make new csv file(list) from csv reader
            for row in reader2:
                emptyl2.append(row)

            #Calculate RMSE
            OldSqResidSum = 0
            BoostDTSqResidSum = 0
            for row in emptyl2:                             #make Sum of Squared Residuals
                for cell in row:
                    if cell == row[-4]:
                        OldSqResidSum = float(cell) + OldSqResidSum
                    if cell == row[-3]:
                        BoostDTSqResidSum = float(cell) + BoostDTSqResidSum
            OldSqResidAvg = OldSqResidSum / len(emptyl2)    #divide by N to get average
            BoostDTResidAvg = BoostDTSqResidSum / len(emptyl2)
            oldRMSE = np.sqrt(OldSqResidAvg)               #calculate RMSE of ESTARRTIME & Boosted Decision Tree
            BoostedDecTree_RMSE = np.sqrt(BoostDTResidAvg)

            #Constructing Correct/Incorrect Predictions
            BoostedDT_Accurate = 0
            BoostedDT_Inaccurate = 0
            for row in emptyl2:
                    if cell == row[-1] and 'Accurate' in cell:
                        BoostedDT_Accurate += 1
                    else:
                        BoostedDT_Inaccurate += 1



            ######################################
            #For Artificial Neural Network (ANN) Predictions
            headerline3 = next(reader3)
            emptyl3=[]
            for row in reader3:
                emptyl3.append(row)

            #Calculate RMSE
            ANNSqResidSum = 0
            for row in emptyl3:
                for cell in row:
                    if cell == row[-3]:
                        ANNSqResidSum = float(cell) + ANNSqResidSum
            ANNSqResidAvg = ANNSqResidSum / len(emptyl3)
            ANN_RMSE = np.sqrt(ANNSqResidAvg)

            #Constructing Correct/Incorrect Predictions
            ANN_Accurate = 0
            ANN_Inaccurate = 0
            for row in emptyl3:
                for cell in row:
                    if cell == row[-1] and 'Accurate' in cell:
                        ANN_Accurate += 1
                    else:
                        ANN_Inaccurate += 1



            #Compile the Error Measures
            finalcsv = []
            finalcsv.append(oldRMSE)
            finalcsv.append(DecForest_RMSE)
            finalcsv.append(BoostedDecTree_RMSE)
            finalcsv.append(ANN_RMSE)
            finalcsv.append(Old_Accurate)
            finalcsv.append(Old_Inaccurate)
            finalcsv.append(DecisionForest_Accurate)
            finalcsv.append(DecisionForest_Inaccurate)
            finalcsv.append(BoostedDT_Accurate)
            finalcsv.append(BoostedDT_Inaccurate)
            finalcsv.append(ANN_Accurate)
            finalcsv.append(ANN_Inaccurate)



            #Write the Final Comparison file
            writer.writeheader()
            writer.writerows({'oldRMSE': row[0], 'Decision Forest Regression RMSE': row[1], 'Boosted Decision Tree Regression RMSE': row[2], 'Neural Network Regression RMSE': row[3], 'Old Accurate Predictions': row[4], 'Old Inaccurate Predictions': row[5], 'Decision Forest Accurate Predictions': row[6], 'Decision Forest Inaccurate Predictions': row[7], 'Boosted Decision Tree Accurate Predictions': row[8], 'Boosted Decision Tree Inaccurate Predictions': row[9], 'Neural Network Accurate Predictions': row[10], 'Neural Network Inaccurate Predictions': row[11]} for row in np.nditer(finalcsv))


main()
```

Comment: Should the first line of your main be `no_of_files = number_of_files()` ?

Comment: @AK47 changed it, still gave the same error:

 line 35, in pathlist
    while self.number_of_files > 0:
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'number_of_files'